# extract substring from a string in python?

Tags: python, substring

I have two strings like below -

```
1)500 Rahway Avenue, Westfield, NJ 07090
2)910 N Harbor Drive, San Diego CA 92101
```

Want to get 2 Expected output-

```
1)Westfield
2)San Diego
```

And

```
1)NJ
2)CA
```

I tried below approach for output NJ and CA -

```
s1.rsplit(" ")[-2]
```

But this is not the right approach.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `s1.rsplit(" ")[-2]` worked for me.  Please show us a complete example to demonstrate how this did not work for you.

Comment: @JohnGordon The issue is that it wouldn't grab the full city name for example 2.

Comment: The data format is inconsistent, which makes this job a lot harder.  In the first string there is a comma after the city name, but in the second string there is no comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the city is placed right before the zip code and that zip code always has two capitals, then using a regular expression you could do it like this:

```
import re

s = """500 Rahway Avenue, Westfield, NJ 07090
910 N Harbor Drive, San Diego CA 92101"""

results = re.findall(r", ([^,]*),? ([A-Z]{2}\b)", s)

print(results)
```

Output:

```
[('Westfield', 'NJ'), ('San Diego', 'CA')]
```

With the `zip` function you can turn that into a sequence of cities and of zipcodes:

```
cities, zipcodes = zip(*re.findall(r", ([^,]*),? ([A-Z]{2}\b)", s))

print(cities)
print(zipcodes)
```

Output:

```
('Westfield', 'San Diego')
('NJ', 'CA')
```

When you deal with separate strings for each line, you could also use that same regex as follows:

```
import re

lst = [
    "500 Rahway Avenue, Westfield, NJ 07090",
    "910 N Harbor Drive, San Diego CA 92101"
]

for s in lst:
    city, zipcode = re.search(r", ([^,]*),? ([A-Z]{2}\b)", s).groups()
    print(city, zipcode)
```

Comment: that's great solution, but I want to separately fetch the city and zipcode?